# Can I enter Thailand on a tourist visa without proof of departure arrangements?

Tags: visas, thailand, tourist-visas, work, working-visas

I have been to Thailand twice in the past, one time on a tourist visa and once on the 1-month visa free entry. Both times I had a return ticket.

I am planning my third trip now and I'm planning on going on a tourist visa. However, I will be studying there for 5 weeks (I have emailed the school and they informed me I will not require a student visa since it is only 5 weeks).

Once I finish studying, I plan on finding a job and will then apply for a work visa. Since I plan on staying and returning to my home country, will I be allowed to enter Thailand without proof of a return flight?

My brother travelled to Thailand around 2 years ago on a tourist visa, without a return flight, and then got a work visa. He had no issue getting into Thailand without the return flight, but had a little trouble leaving since that time.

Comment: To those voting to close and move to expats - wtf?  This question has nothing to do with expats.  The fact he may way to work later is not relevant to the question actually being asked (entering without a return ticket)!

Comment: What nationality are you?

Comment: I am from New Zealand

Answer (score 3):

The answer to that is "it depends". I go to Thailand every 6 weeks, give or take, and was never asked for a proof of onward journey. Even when walking/driving to Laos or Cambodia, and coming back shortly after.

But that's because I've established a pattern of short visits (I don't think I ever stayed longer than a week at a time in Thailand) and because I don't look like one of those people who live in Thailand on visa exemptions/tourist visas.

So while one person may be let in without a single question, the next one might be asked for a plane ticket. In your case, if you're going on a tourist visa, you most probably won't be asked for much, or anything at all, really. You've been pre-approved, and that's good enough for Immigration officers. As you may have noticed in your previous visits, they're people of few words.

Comment: Concur in most cases.  Years ago, immigration didnt care about unlimited border hops, but now after 5-6 entries within 6 or 12 month period, immigration may start to ask questions if Visa Exempt entry (and in some cases SETVs) But OP needs to list nationality.

Comment: I am from New Zealand and upon looking into it further i think i would be better to apply for the 90 day visa as it can be upgraded to a work permit, where as a tourist visa needs to be upgraded to a non immigration b visa before getting a work permit. But my question about the return ticket remains. I Emailed the embassy but am still waiting for a reply